# What about non finitely generated groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Finite groups and finitely generated groups are intensively studied, but are there interesting investigations on non finitely generated groups?

I already know some references for abelian groups, so I am rather interested by nonabelian groups; are they nice enough to hope general results? Maybe are there interesting links with set theory?

Comment: Topological groups, for example Lie groups are not finitely generated. Another interested example is profinite groups (they are inverse limits of finite groups) or pro-$p$ groups (profinite groups which are a kind of generalization of the finite $p$-groups)

Comment: *Locally finite* groups are groups whose *finitely* generated subgroups are finite. Finite group theory is quite helpful for investigating locally finite groups, but they do need new techniques (see for example [these classnotes](http://www.math.msu.edu/~meier/Classnotes/LFG/LFG.pdf)).